# Проблема с подключением openvpn

Tags: linux, openvpn

Я не однократно пытался подключиться к .ovpn в сервисе "tryhackme.com"(пытался так же подключиться в vpnbook, но так же мимо) . Я искал ответ на этот вопрос везде, пробовал сам решить проблему, через обновление openvpn до последней версии, переустанавливал os linux и через виртуальную машину, но всё мимо. В коде я указал то, что мне выдаёт openvpn, самое как мне кажется, это первые 3 строчки

```
2023-02-08 20:28:39 WARNING: Compression for receiving enabled. Compression has been used in the past to break encryption. Sent packets are not compressed unless "allow-compression yes" is also set.
```

2023-02-08 20:28:39 --cipher is not set. Previous OpenVPN version defaulted to BF-CBC as fallback when cipher negotiation failed in this case. If you need this fallback please add '--data-ciphers-fallback BF-CBC' to your configuration and/or add BF-CBC to --data-ciphers.
2023-02-08 20:28:39 OpenVPN 2.5.8 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Nov  1 2022
2023-02-08 20:28:39 library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022, LZO 2.10
2023-02-08 20:28:39 OpenSSL: error:0480006C:PEM routines::no start line
2023-02-08 20:28:39 OpenSSL: error:0A080009:SSL routines::PEM lib
2023-02-08 20:28:39 Cannot load inline certificate file
2023-02-08 20:28:39 Exiting due to fatal error

Кто сможет помочь с проблемой, буду очень благадарен. Если будет удобнее описать решение проблемы и узнать подробности, пишити в телегу @Luxgen01